# Convert Excel table based on Column Values using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Have this Table below ,
[image]

I would Like to use the Header Column to transform the Table like this
[image]

Any Help It will be great, Best regards
Hala

Comment: The Idea is to use the Values in the header column to form three extra columns then put the equivalent values under neath each of the new columns

Comment: And keep information in the other columns consistent ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily solve this puzzle with a pivot table.  Put the amount field into the `values` section of the pivot and set to get sums.  Put the header field into the `columns` section of the pivot.  And put the rest fields into the `rows` section of the pivot.  Pivot will auto-show the grandtotal and subtotals per rows but you can remove them easily with a right click on it.  And finally to get a view like a data table click `repeat all item labels` in pivot's `report layout`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks , I keep trying selecting the repeat all item labels from the field settings but no change..

Comment: Where I can find the report layout?